# SQL's "Insert Into" is Working..... but not

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-insert

So this is one of the more frustrating coding problems I've had to deal with in awhile.

I make small databases all the time through automation and I've always used this method, and I've always been able to see the results right away through the use of "Show table data"

So I have 1000's of files all containing a few lines of data, my script goes through the files and uploads the relevant data to a database.

My program reads the data fine, inserts the data into the table fine (or says it does), but the .mdf does not update, and after the program exits - there is always 0 lines of data saved.

I've tried my normal method (which i've succesfully used a dozen times) on two different computer without luck.

So the DB starts with nothing in it.

So here is the code:

```
  Using check2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Count (*) From Drops", con)
      MsgBox(check2.ExecuteScalar) 
      //This returns 0 
  End Using

        For Each newfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc)
              //A lot of uninteresting code
                Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr)
                      con.Open()
                      Using check As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Drops WHERE Time='" & time & "' AND Lat='" & theLat & "' AND Long='" & theLong & "'", con)

                    If check.ExecuteScalar = 0 Then
                        Using Update As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Drops(Vendor, Model, AndVer, Time, SubType, Lat, Long, LAC, CellID) VALUES('" & Vendor & "','" & Model & "','" & AndroidVer & "','" & time & "','" & SubType & "'," & theLat & "," & theLong & "," & LAC & ",'" & cellID & "')", con)
                            Update.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            added += 1
                        End Using
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
         Next

  Using check3 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Count (*) From Drops", con)
      MsgBox(check3.ExecuteScalar) 
      //This returns over 1000
  End Using
```

So I know that the INSERT command works because check3 is returning a 1000 entries from "Drops" when it reported 0 at the begining of the script. So my question is - where is all the data going???

The mdf file never seems to update, everytime I go back into them after the script ends, they always contain 0 entries - and I've checked the mdf file located in the bin and in the main project itself. Is there a setting or a switch that I accidently hit?

The weirder thing is, I thought this might be a debug issue - so I published the project thinking that it would start saving data once it got out of the debug environment - but nope. The mdf file never gets above 3mb's (blank) no matter how many files are written to it.

Any help is always and greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
 -Z

Comment: Sounds like you have some degree of uncertainty as to which database this is being inserted into. That would be my first place to check. Clearly this is not 'all' the code - some outer code calls all of this. Are you certain that code is not doing something unexpected? Is it just one input file that fails or many? I also suggest using SQL Profiler to observe the inserts as they happen. Maybe the data is being truncated afterwards or the table is being dropped / recreated.

Comment: I would say that what you are looking at is 80-85% of the code... The projects only function is to parse a file and to upload the relevant data to the DB.... Check3 is at the very end of the script, so the count(*) is the very last thing that happens before the application closes and it is returning that the table is supposed to have over a 1000 lines in it.... The connstring includes "application.startuppath" so it will be where ever the exe is located... with that being said, nothing updates no matter if its published or ran from the debugging environment.

Comment: Perhaps to remove uncertainty you could temporarily hard code the path. After that, hard code an invalid path. Again not seeing all the code, there's no guarantee you are using the same `con` object in the three calls but I assume you are? Any reason you are opening the connection inside the loop? wouldn't it be faster to open it outside the loop once and reuse it? I don't have a magic bullet answer only suggestions for slicing up and isolating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you're using a connection string in this way

```
Dim connStr As String = "Server=your_server;Database=|DataDirectory|\name_of_db;User Id=user_name;Password=my_password"
```

or if it's located at your `config.file`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\yourDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If so, please bear on mind that sometimes `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\...` is problematic when debugging. Please bear on mind that you'll have another database in `\bin\debug` at your project folder when you are debugging your code. Probably you're updating the records in this database instead the original one.

Try to set an absolute path and check if the records are being updated.

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\yourProjectFolder\YourDBName.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

There’s a property `Copy to Output Directory` and the default value is `Copy if newer` (if you’re using `.mdf` or `.mdb` file, the default value is `Copy always`). You could check this **[MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx)** to learn what this property means. In short, the local database file will be copied to Output directory, and THAT database is the one that will get updated.

If you don’t want Visual Studio to copy the database file for you, you could set the Copy to `Output Directory` property to `Do not copy`. Then it’s your choice when and how to overwrite the database file. Of course, you still need two copies of database file: at design time, you’re using the database file in solution directory, while at run time, you’re modifying the one in output directory.

Comment: Mostly right, I think the big thing was that I was using "Copy Always." I switched it to "Do Not Copy" ... I also figured out a better way to load the DB in and out of Visual Studio so that I can see the progress of the debug testing. Thank you all for the help